# Why do we need an offset value

Tags: java, swing, jtextpane

So my code is working, may be its not the prettiest or most efficient but for now its getting the job done. However, my question is why do I need certain offset values, like I have a + 1 at places for some of my functions and my line numbering has a + 2. These magic numbers are a bit confusing, because they make the program work as needed, but why do they do it? I have these + 1 added to the total and I understand a bit why they work, but still don't have a concrete explanation for these magic numbers. If you could tell me their signifiance that would be great. Here is some of the code to reference.

```
private String getLineNumbersText()
{
    int counter = 0;
    int caretPosition = textArea.getDocument().getLength();
    Element root = textArea.getDocument().getDefaultRootElement();
    StringBuilder lineNumbersTextBuilder = new StringBuilder();
    lineNumbersTextBuilder.append("1").append(System.lineSeparator());

    for (int elementIndex = 2; elementIndex < root.getElementIndex(caretPosition) +2; 
        elementIndex++)
    {
        lineNumbersTextBuilder.append(elementIndex).append(System.lineSeparator());
    }
    return lineNumbersTextBuilder.toString();
}
}
public void goToLine(JTextPane text)
{
   String lineToSearch = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Line Number: ");
   int total = 0;
   int lineNum = 0;
   for (String line : text.getText().split("\n"))
   {
     lineNum +=1;
     String lineNumStr = lineNum + "";
     if (lineNumStr.compareTo(lineToSearch) == 0)
     {
        if( line == null)
        {
           text.setCaretPosition(total);
        }
        text.setCaretPosition(total);
        break;
     }
     total += line.length() + 1;

   }
 }
 public void search(JTextPane text) 
 { 
  Document myText = text.getDocument();
  final StyleContext cont = StyleContext.getDefaultStyleContext();
  final AttributeSet reset = cont.addAttribute(cont.getEmptySet(), 
     StyleConstants.Foreground,Color.GREEN);
  String wordToSearch = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Word to search for:");
  Highlighter highlighter = text.getHighlighter();
  highlighter.removeAllHighlights();
  HighlightPainter painter = new DefaultHighlighter.DefaultHighlightPainter(Color.pink);

  int m;
  int total = 0;
  for (String line : text.getText().split("\n")) 
  {
     m = line.indexOf(wordToSearch);
     if(m == -1)
     {
        if(isUnix())
        {
        total += line.length() + 1;
        }
        else if(isWindows())
        {
           total += line.length();
        }
        else if(isMac())
        {
           total += line.length() + 1;
        }
        else
        {
           total += line.length() + 1;
        }
        continue;
     }
     try
     {
        highlighter.addHighlight(total + m, total + m + wordToSearch.length(), painter);
     }catch(BadLocationException ex)
     {}
     while(true)
     {
        m = line.indexOf(wordToSearch, m + 1);

        if (m == -1)
        {

           break;
        }
        try{
        highlighter.addHighlight(total + m, total + m + wordToSearch.length(), painter);
        }catch(BadLocationException e)
        {
        }
     }
     if(isUnix())
        {
        total += line.length() + 1;
        }
        else if(isWindows())
        {
           total += line.length();
        }
        else if(isMac())
        {
           total += line.length() + 1;
        }
        else
        {
           total += line.length() + 1;
        }
        continue;
  }
  try
        {
         myText.insertString(total,"", reset);
        }
        catch(BadLocationException ex)
        {

        }
  }
```

Comment: Sure, so the line numbering basically displays line numbers on the left side of the text pane. The search highlights the word to search, the go to line goes to the specified line.

Comment: What's the `if (line==null)` statement supposed to be doing? It seems to be setting a caret position to the same thing it is going to be set to anyway

Comment: Yea, I think that might have been a bit redundant, when I was trying to make something work out

Answer (score 2):

Code seems a bit complicated so I'm not sure what it all does.

However, maybe these links will help simplify the code:

1. [Text and New Lines](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2009/02/07/text-and-new-lines/) - I would guess that because Window has a two character line delimiter your code has exception logic. The solution would be to use `textPane.getDocument().getText(...)`.
2. [Text Utilities](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2008/10/26/text-utilities/) might be easier to understand and use. Then don't use magic numbers.
3. Check out the `Utilities` class. Methods like getRowStart(...) and getRowEnd(....) will make is easier to extract the text since once you know the start/end offsets you can just use the getText(...) method with those parameters.
4. If you are trying to use line number then you can also check out [Text Component Line Number](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2009/05/23/text-component-line-number/).